# How to update contract that has already been published to nodeos?

Tags: smart-contract, cleos

I published a contract to my localnet using:

```
cleos set contract myaccount mycontractfolder -p myaccount
```

Then I made some updates to the code, and want to publish them, I type the same command again, but this time, I get the error message:

```
Error 3160008: Contract is already running this version of code
Error Details:
contract is already running this version of code
pending console output:
```

How can I publish the contract updates without restarting `nodeos`?

Comment: did you recompile? your command looks correct but you need to recompile after modifications

Comment: Yes I recompiled.

Comment: could it be that the change didn't update the wasm as it got optimised out? maybe you could try introducing a new function or a print function

Comment: You are right! The wasm code was not updated because the change was optimized out. If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certain small code changes get optimised out by the WASM compiler, resulting in an identical `.wasm` file, so `nodeos` may reject the update.

Try making a more significant code update such as introducing a new function or calling `eosio::print()`, and you can see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should write or edit new code in it, and recompile it.

try below:

```
eosiocpp -g path/to/mycontractfolder.abi path/to/mycontractfolder.cpp
eosiocpp -o path/to/mycontractfolder.wast path/to/mycontractfolder.cpp
```

If you're using docker, you should send your contract to container via `docker cp`.

Comment: You wrote this answer after the comments on the question explained already that he did recompile the code. Read the comments on a question as well before writing an answer, to make sure you get all the details.

Comment: @AndresBerrios Thanks. I'll check the comments next time.

Answer (score 0):

@confused00 is right in that you need to make significant changes because of wasm optimazation. I want to add that don't forget to update the `EOSIO_ABI` macro at the bottom of the contract. Too many times I have forgotten this and wondered why it wasn't updating.